# How do I increment a counter variable in a template (Django)?

Tags: django, button, counter, increment

I have a model with a variable: counter.

So I have that counter displayed in the template like this:

```
<h2> Counter is : {%for Click in counter %} {{ Click.counter }}{% endfor %} </h2>
```

But is it possible to have a button that whenever a user clicks on it, it increments that Models variable by 1?

```
models.py

class Click(models.Model):
counter = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.counter)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make any changes in the database based on user action, you need a view. Either you can just have a standard HTML link that goes to the URL mapped to that view, or you can write some Ajax, or use a form, but either way you need to send something to the backend.

Comment: But a form wouldnt be suitable in my case, as I just want a button with an action, right?

Comment: No, buttons don't work outside of forms. Your form can be empty apart from the button. Or, as I say, use a link styled to look like a button if you don't mind it being a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: Could you please help me a hand on how to do that?

Comment: An empty form with a button and `action="{% url 'increment_counter' %}"` that links to your Django views is what you're looking for.